# Connect to secure web socket server on RasPi from Windows client

Tags: ssh, server, sockets

I have an architecture as follows:

- **Server**: secure web socket server implemented in Python and running on RasPi device(s)
- **Client**: web app (https) running in a browser on Windows machines and connecting to the web socket server on one of the RasPi devices

I can't buy a signed certificate, as it's a professional context and the decision is not in my hands.
So I have to stick with self-signed certificates created with openssl.

I also can't revert to an unsecure web socket (which works, for testing purposes), since my web app is running in a secure context.

My question: is there any way to provide such a self-signed certificate to the browser on the Windows machines? (Preferably, without manually installing the certificate on every Windows machine.)

Or is there some other option that I don't see, to connect to a secure web socket server remotely?

Unfortunately, my knowledge about the intricacies of certificates is quite meager (not even sure if I am asking the "right question"), so I appreciate any pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was in need of a certificate, I simply installed `certbot` package which is an automated certificate updater working with  [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). If you can run a public web-server on your Pi, even temporarily, running `certbot` will use it to get you a certificate valid for 90 days for the public domain name your web server uses. It will be stored in

```
/etc/letsencrypt/live/your.domain.name/
```

Note that web browsers typically expect the certificate chain (`fullchain.pem`) and not just the certificate itself (`cert.pem`), so your server should send the chain during the TLS handshake.

There is an auto-update service which will try to automatically renew the certificate when there's less than 30 days left, so if your Pi is online regularly, you'll have a valid certificate indefinitely.

If you can't use `certbot` (e.g. no way to get a domain name), you'll have to make your browser trust a self-signed certificate. The exact process is browser-specific, e.g. in Firefox you can visit the page, confirm a security exception and then set `security.certerrors.permanentOverride` to `true` in `about:config`. Alternatively, go to preferences -> certificates -> authorities and import your self-signed certificate there.

Importing your own certificate will put it on the top level, so there is no "chain" in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed big picture view! Indeed, at the moment we have no domain name, as this is an internal tool that is implemented and used only in the LAN; it might change in the future. Anyway, your information points me in the right direction!

Comment: PS. I will award you the bounty, I just have to wait for the min one day duration to pass :)

Comment: @ACEG Thanks, that's great to hear. Were you able to install your self-signed cert then? If not, don't hesitate to ping me in a comment if you still need help with something.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the kind offer! I managed to install the certificate in chrome and now I can access the remote wss from my web app :)